# Shapefiles colored according to corresponding values

Tags: matlab, colormap

I have the following problem. Given are data in a table consisiting of two columns:

- **column1**: numbers for corresponding geographic zones (e.g. zone 11, which stands for Munich)
- **column2**: a certain value in that zone (e.g. Peak Ground Acceleration, PGA)

I would like to display these zones with their corresponding values (e.g. PGA's) on a map. unequal values should be represented in unequal colors. For example

- zone1  PGA=12  color=[1.0 1.0 0.0]
- zone2  PGA=17  color=[1.0 0.9 0.5]
- zone3  PGA=25  color=[0.6 1.0 1.0]
- zone1  PGA=12  color=[1.0 1.0 0.0]

The data contains about 200 zones, and in total about 160 different zones and therefore colors. What would you suggest to set for each value a certain color (same values = same color).

Thank you in advance for your help.
Best regards.

Comment: What is a map? Is it e.g a color map or a geographical map? What do you want the colour to represent? That would influence the colour choice.

Comment: It is basically a geographic map. Different zones on this map should then be colored differently according to a physical value (peak ground acceleration). Colors represent different ground acceleration values, for example: Bay area in California (region/zone) in red due to a large PGA value.

Comment: your question is a bit unclear. The question you have asked is what colours or colour scheme you should choose but I get the feeling the real question is how you would apply different colours to areas of an image.

Comment: The question basically is: I have a matrix. the matrix has the size 200x2. 200 = number of geographic locations. 2 columns: column1 --> location, column 2 --> physical value. For each geographic location, there is a physical value. Now, I would like to visualize that: colors representing physical value in a certain region.

Comment: You still haven't answered whether you want advice of what colours to choose or how to colour an image in Matlab. I assume the latter because you have tagged the question with `Matlab`.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you have zone1 having a PGA=12 in both cases. Is this always the case, or with zone1 ever have a different PGA? This answer assumes that it will always have the same PGA.

```
myColorArray = jet(160); %assuming you have 160 unique colors/zones of the 200
```

Here `jet` is your simple built in function to create a nice Mx3 colormap

If you want to randomize this so similar colors aren't right next to each other you could do:

```
myColorArray(randperm(160),:)  = myColorArray;
```

Now I don't know if your actual first column for zones is just a number from 1-160, but if it is you could just use that as your index to correspond the colors.

```
FullColorArray(:,YourMatrix(:,1)) = myColorArray(:,YourMatrix(:,1));
```

If it's not, you could use the `unique` command to create an index and work with that.

```
LimitedZoneMat = unique(YourMatrix(:,1));
```

Or if I misunderstood and you want your colors to correlate to PGA value, you could just use that as an index.